# Create a percentage discount coupon with a maximum value

Tags: commerce

Need to have a coupon that follows this basic logic:

```
IF (Commerce % Coupon Granted amount > Max Value) THEN 
    Commerce % Coupon amount = Max Value
ELSE
    Commerce % Coupon amount = % of ORDER
```

For example:

10% with a max of $100.

> Order value = 500, Discount = 50 (10% of 500)
>   Order value = 1000, Discount = 100 (10% of 1000)
>   Order value = 1500, Discount = 100 (flat 100)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the latest version of [Commerce Discount](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_discount) and [Commerce Coupon](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_coupon), you can accomplish this with just two rules connected to a single coupon code.

1. Create a Coupon Code by going to Admin→Store→Coupons->Create Coupon Code. Save it.
2. Create a new Discount (Admin→Store->Discounts->Create). Set it to **Order Discount** and add a **Total amount** condition. Set the condition to **less than** and the amount to **2000**. Set the percentage discount as you desire. Finally, add the coupon code from step 1 to this discount and save it.
3. Create a another Discount. Set it to **Order Discount** and add a **Total amount** condition. Set the condition to **greater than or equal to** and the amount to **2000**. Set the flat discount as you desire. Finally, add the coupon code from step 1 to this discount and save it.

Now, when a customer checks out, the coupon will attempt to apply both discounts, but because of the condition, only one will apply: $200 if the order is $2000 or over, and 10% if the order is $1999.99 and under.